# React-bootstrap onSelect method to change state

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

i have a dropdown button, when i select a `<menuItem>`from the button.

im trying to run a function that `setState({fltrName:"pentium})`.

the thing is that it doesent work the function will run and it `console.log()`,
but it doesnt change the state and why is that ? 
here is the function

```
     fltrFunc:function(name){

       function fltrPick(pick){        
         this.setState({fltrName:pick}) // sholud set to "pentium"
         console.log(this.state.fltrName) //but console "proccessor" (dosent change)
        }

        switch(name){
           case "processors":
             return (
              <DropdownButton id="dropdownBtn" bsSize="xsmall"  title={name} >
               <MenuItem eventKey="1" onSelect={fltrPick.bind(this,"pentium")} >pentium </MenuItem>

          // above should run the func fltrPick() and change the state

               <MenuItem eventKey="2">i3</MenuItem>
               <MenuItem eventKey="3">i7</MenuItem> 
               </DropdownButton>
                    )
             braek;
          default: return <DropdownButton title="nothing for now"> </DropdownButton>
                   }
      },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing you need to know is that `setState` is **asynchronous**, which means that when you call setState, it calls pending state transition and updates it later.

That being said, it means that console.log() will write old value of `state` even though it changed. State gets updated afterwards.
Also, I would advise you to use ES7 arrow syntax when passing functions, so onSelect would look like this `onSelect={() => fltrPick('pentium'))}` and function like this

```
fltrPick = (pick) =>  {
    this.setState({fltrName:pick})       
}
```

(you don't need to bind it this way).

Comment: the thing now is that it gives me an error "Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined" why is it undefined what is not binded here ?

Comment: Updated answer accordingly, I forgot to rewrite function to arrow syntax aswell.